# How to push html form in to an array in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is this possible to push a html form into an array in php each time save button is clicked ? It should append the saved form into the array in php.
The connection between client and server side via ajax is working. I'm getting the receiving the POST parameters.

Just similarly to a shopping cart, very very light and not complicated. Just save the catalog orders in an array. Then preview this array. If the preview is valid , click send button and send an email.

But for now having troubles with understanding how can it be possible to push the multiple forms into an array and store this in a session.

what i have done so far:

html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last name"><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br><br>
    <select name="selectCatalog" id="selectCatalog">
        <option selected disabled hidden style="display:none;" value=""></option>
        <option value="16">Main Catalog</option>
        <option value="17">Sasion Catalog</option>
        <option value="18">Specific Catalog</option>
    </select><br>
    <select name="selectCatalogLanguage" id="selectCatalogLanguage">
        <option selected disabled hidden style="display:none;" value=""></option>
        <option value="ger">German</option>
        <option value="pol">Polish</option>
        <option value="eng">English</option>
    </select><br>
    <label for="selectCatalogCover">Cover</label>
    <select name="selectCatalogCover" id="selectCatalogCover">
        <option selected disabled hidden style="display:none;" value=""></option>
        <option value="s43">Standard Cover</option>
        <option value="s18">Business Cover</option>
        <option value="s19">Promotion Cover</option>
    </select><br>
    <label for="selectColor">Eindruck</label>
    <select name="selectColor" id="selectColor">
        <option selected disabled hidden style="display:none;" value=""></option>
        <option value="bw">Back/White</option>
        <option value="col">Color</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
    <button type="button" name="order">Save order</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$('button[name=order]').on('click', function(){
var $myform = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {data: $myform},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

php:

```
session_start();
$orderArray = array();

if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    parse_str($_POST['data'], $searcharray);
    $selectCatalog = $searcharray['selectCatalog'];
    $selectCatalogLanguage = $searcharray['selectCatalogLanguage'];
    $selectCatalogCover = $searcharray['selectCatalogCover'];
    $selectColor = $searcharray['selectColor'];

    $quantity = $searcharray['quantity']; 
    $sku = $selectCatalog.$selectCatalogCover.$selectCatalogLanguage.$selectColor;
    array_push($orderArray, $sku);
}
$_SESSION['orders'] = $orderArray;
var_dump($orderArray);
```

Comment: Why not just store the info in localStorage in the client until it's all ready to be posted/submitted? Then there's no need for any server calls at all.

Comment: do you mean do save all the data in javascript ?

Comment: Yes. Then you can also make the data persistent across sessions (if the user closes the browser, etc) Here's some info about localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Can I suggest you start by doing a simple `print_r($_POST);` so you see what $_POST actually looks like

Comment: And maybe `$_SESSION['orders'][] = $orderArray;` might allow you to persist more than one iteration

Comment: `Array ( [data] => selectCatalog=17&selectCatalogLanguage=ger&selectCatalogCover=s18&selectColor=col)`

Answer (score 0):

Here the php Code How you store multiple form details in one session. it also help you to easily show in perfect format.

```
session_start();
$orderArray = array();

if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    parse_str($_POST['data'], $searcharray);
    $orderArray['Catalog'] = $searcharray['selectCatalog'];
    $orderArray['CatalogLanguage'] = $searcharray['selectCatalogLanguage'];
    $orderArray['CatalogCover'] = $searcharray['selectCatalogCover'];
    $orderArray['Color'] = $searcharray['selectColor'];
    $orderArray['Quantity'] = $searcharray['quantity']; 
}
$_SESSION['orders'][] = $orderArray;
var_dump($orderArray);
```